# Killall doesn't work if I call it from a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, taskkill, ash

I'm starting a `tcpdump` inside a script and I also kill it from the same script. So I'm currently using the `killall` command for this: The script gets executed from an `udev` rule: This is the section, which should terminate the `tcpdump`: In addition I also use `-s SIDKILL`, because I've read that this could also help.

What is the problem that `killall` doesn't terminate the `tcpdump`. When I start the script manually it is all working properly.

```
 if [[ "$pid1" != "" ]];then
          sudo killall -s SIGKILL tcpdump
          sh /tmp/scripts/autoumount.sh &
          sudo kill -9 $$
          echo "autodump stopped"
```

Comment: Can your user execute `sudo` without a password?

Comment: BTW, sigkill is a bad idea here -- it'll prevent tcpdump from flushing its buffers, so you get the end of your capture cut off. Better to stick with the default sigterm.

Comment: Also, how do you expect anything after a `kill -9 $$` (killing the script itself) to execute?

Comment: Also, what user is this script running as? Better to just run the whole thing as root (and perhaps drop privileges for specific commands as appropriate) than to allow `sudo` to be run without a TTY with an unlimited range of arguments.

Comment: BTW, `if [[ $pid1 ]]` would be a cleaner way to write your `if` statement. Quoting isn't needed in `[[ ]]`, which suppresses string-splitting and glob expansion, and the default test action is `-n`, checking for a non-empty string.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I actually don't really need the things after the kill -9, it should be the end.

Comment: BTW, to diagnose the actual failure, I'd start by collecting stderr from the script's run (perhaps with the `set -x` flag to capture commands run), and move on to sysdig if that were insufficiently illuminating.

Comment: (When run by udev, you'll want to redirect stderr internally; at the top of your script: `exec 2>/path/to/logfile; set -x`)

Comment: ...my guess, though, is that you haven't configured `sudo` to be able to run successfully without a TTY -- which is fine, because anything kicked off by udev is running as root, so you don't need (and can just remove) the `sudo`s anyhow.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're starting tcpdump from the same script, there's no need for `killall`.

If you're running multiple background processes, use an array, like so:

```
pids=( )                 # initialize empty array
tcpdump & pids+=( "$!" ) # extend said array
```

...later on, you can kill those PIDs:

```
kill "${pids[@]}"
```

Comment: I already did this option, but I messed it up a little bit, because it started more than just one tcpdump so I just use killall now.

Comment: What code, precisely, starts more than one tcpdump? Even if there's more than one thread in a process (and you have an OS that gives threads individual process table entries), killing the main one should shut them all down. By contrast, if you're running in a loop, you should collect the PIDs in an array.